# Convert Date Format in Informatica

Tags: oracle, datetime, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I am trying to convert source field of DateTime attribute of format 03/08/2021 00:00:00 to target field of DateTime attribute to format 2021-03-08 00:00:00.

I tried using `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATE_CON,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

but got following error:

> TT_11132 Transformation [Expression] had an error evaluating output column [DATE_CON]. Error message is [<> [TO_DATE]: invalid string for converting to Date ... t:TO_DATE(u:TO_CHAR(t:<03/08/2021 00:00:00>,u:'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI;SS'),u:'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS ')].

How can I resolve this error? DataType of both source and target is DateTime.

Comment: Are the source and target Oracle databases (given the tags)?  If so, Oracle doesn't have a `datetime` data type.  It has `date`.  And it has `timestamp`.  Neither of which have a human-readable format.  They're always stored in a packed binary format that is independent of the way the application may convert the `date` or `timestamp` to a human-readable string.

Comment: You have semicolon in you rinformatica expression. I am sure this is missed. Pls fix it and it will be all good. This is from your error msg, pls note there is a semicolon between MI and SS.  `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI;SS'),u:'YYY`.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try to use the below format :

```html
TO_date (TO_CHAR(DATE_CON),'YYYYMMDDHH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Date_Con has datetime datatype, To_DATE input should be a string

Comment: what you get if you convert date_con to string ? TO_date (to_char(DATE_CON),'YYYYMMDDHH24:MI:SS')